# Print Wesite to PDF using VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, printing

I am trying to save HTML as PDF using VBA.

I don't know how to check what is the default printer change it to Microsoft Print to PDF and then back to the old printer.

Below is my code: I search something on Google, then enter the links on the first Google Search page and then I would like to print searches to PDF.

```vba
Sub Main()

    Dim search As String
    Dim save_path As String
    Dim number As Integer

    number = 5
    save_path = ""

    Dim query As String
    query = InputBox("Enter here your search", "Google Search")
    search = query
    search = Replace(search, " ", "+")
    PDFFolderSelection save_path, search

    Debug.Print save_path, search
    Google_Search search, save_path, number
End Sub

Sub Google_Search(search As String, save_path As String, number As Integer)    
    Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    IE.Navigate "http://google.com/#q=" & search
    IE.Visible = True

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document


    Dim RCS As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim RC As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set RCS = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("rc")
    Dim Atags As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Atag As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Dim URLs As New Collection
    Dim URL As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set URLs = Nothing


    For Each RC In RCS
     Dim RS As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
     Dim R As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
     Set RS = RC.getElementsByClassName("r")
        For Each R In RS
         Set Atags = R.getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each Atag In Atags
             URLs.Add Atag
            Next Atag
        Next R
    Next RC

    For Each URL In URLs
        Dim IEs As InternetExplorerMedium
        Set IEs = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        str_text = Replace(URL.getAttribute("href"), "", "")
        str_text = Replace(str_text, "", "")
        'Debug.Print str_text
        IEs.Navigate str_text
        IEs.Visible = True
        Do While IEs.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IEs.Busy
        Loop

        IEs.Quit
        Set IEs = Nothing
    Next URL

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: use google to find out how to check the default printer and how to change it

Comment: i tried to find the solution but i havent find any thats why i ask question on stack

Answer (score 1):

My code looks like this and now i would like to print website to PDF

```
Dim sPrinter As String
Dim sDefaultPrinter As String
Debug.Print "Default printer: ", Application.ActivePrinter
sDefaultPrinter = Application.ActivePrinter ' store default printer
sPrinter = GetPrinterFullName("Microsoft Print to PDF")
If sPrinter = vbNullString Then ' no match
    Debug.Print "No match"
Else
    Application.ActivePrinter = sPrinter
    Debug.Print "Temp printer: ", Application.ActivePrinter
    ' do something with the temp printer
    ' Przechodzenie przez strony wraz z zapisem
    For Each URL In URLs
     Dim IEs As InternetExplorerMedium
     Set IEs = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
     str_text = Replace(URL.getAttribute("href"), "", "")
     str_text = Replace(str_text, "", "")

     IEs.Navigate str_text
     IEs.Visible = True
     Do While IEs.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IEs.Busy
     Loop



     'HERE I WOLULD LIKE TO PRINT IEs TO PDF (specific path, and filename:)


     IEs.Quit
     Set IEs = Nothing
    i = i + 1
    If i = 5 Then Exit For
    Next URL
    Application.ActivePrinter = sDefaultPrinter ' restore default printer
End If
Debug.Print "Default printer: ", Application.ActivePrinter
```

Answer (score 0):

this took less than 10 minutes to find

just change your `default printer` in windows and check the value of `Application.ActivePrinter` to get the exact name of the printer that you want to use

there are ways to get a list of system printers by executing system calls.

```
Option Explicit

Sub switchPrinters()
    Dim ptr As String

    ptr = Application.ActivePrinter
    Application.ActivePrinter = "HP Deskjet 3520 USB on Ne03:" ' "printer_name on port_name" 
    Activesheet.Printout
    Application.ActivePrinter = ptr

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can i print website to a specific folder. I have a path to the folder.

Comment: that is not your original question. please submit another post for this question.